# Rollup Summary Fields and Formula Fields are not writable but how to call them in test class

Tags: unit-test, controller

Can any one help me out with test class code coverage .I have written a test class for a controller having wrapper class and their are rollup summary and formula fields which are not writable but how to call them in a test class and  cover the code which is zero. Any help very much appreciated.

1)Rollup Summary Fields and Formula Fields are not writable but how to call them in test class.

2)How to call 'IF' Conditions.If there are 'n' no of conditions then we need to use 'n' no of methods .

**Code:**

```
@istest
Public class  TestInvoiceController{
static Testmethod void Invoicemethodtest(){

 test.startTest();

 Date closeDt = Date.Today();

// set up Account and Verify that the results are as expected.
Account a = new Account();
a.Name = 'icrm test acc';
insert a;
// set up opportunity and Verify that the results are as expected.
opportunity op = new opportunity(Name='test DIE 4/6/2015' ,  AccountId= a.Id,StageName = 'Prospecting', 
                                   CloseDate = closeDt, Shipment_Info__c='test',
                                   Shipping_Address_Line1__c='Road No 37',
                                   Shipping_Address_Line2__c='Jubilee Hills',
                                   Shipping_Address_Line3__c='Land Mark Neerus',
                                   Shipping_City__c='Hyd',
                                   Shipping_State_Province__c='TS',
                                   Shipping_Zipcode__c='500081',
                                   Shipping_Country__c ='India',
                                   Bill_of_Lading__c='This is waybill1 this is waybill 2 waybill3 -34958309458 waybill - 44570375');

  insert op;


  // set up product and Verify that the results are as expected.

  Product2 pro = new Product2(Product_Line__c='DIE',Name='BXCD',Product_Code_Item_Number__c='BXCD24',isActive=true);
  insert pro;


   // set up pricebook and Verify that the results are as expected.

 Pricebook2 pb2 = new Pricebook2(Name='DIE');
 insert pb2;
  PriceBook2 pb2Standard = [select Id from Pricebook2 where IsStandard=true];


   // set up pricebookentry and Verify that the results are as expected.

PricebookEntry pbe =new PricebookEntry(unitprice=0.01,Product2Id=pro.Id,Pricebook2Id=pb2Standard.Id,isActive=true,UseStandardPrice = false
);
 insert pbe;


  // set up opportunitylineitem and Verify that the results are as expected.

 OpportunityLineItem OPplineitem= new OpportunityLineItem (Quantity=2, OpportunityId=op.Id,UnitPrice=0.01,PriceBookEntryId=pbe.Id);
 insert OPplineitem;

  test.stopTest();

  InvoiceController ic = new InvoiceController();
  apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().put('opId',op.id);


  }

 static Testmethod void Invoicemethodtest1(){
 test.startTest();

 Date closeDt = Date.Today();


  // set up account and Verify that the results are as expected.

 Account a = new Account();
a.Name = 'icrm test acc';
insert a;
// set up opportunity and Verify that the results are as expected.
opportunity op = new opportunity(Name='test NonDIE 4/6/2015' , AccountId= a.Id,StageName = 'Prospecting', 
                                   CloseDate = closeDt,Shipment_Info__c='test',
                                   Shipping_Address_Line1__c='Road No 37',
                                   Shipping_Address_Line2__c='Jubilee Hills',
                                   Shipping_Address_Line3__c='Land Mark Neerus',
                                   Shipping_City__c='Hyd',
                                   Shipping_State_Province__c='TS',
                                   Shipping_Zipcode__c='500081',
                                   Shipping_Country__c ='India' , 
                                   Bill_of_Lading__c='This is waybill1 this is waybill 2 waybill3 -34958309458 waybill - 44570375');

  insert op;

  // set up product and Verify that the results are as expected.
  Product2 pro = new Product2(Product_Line__c='NONDIE',Name='BXRC',Product_Code_Item_Number__c='BXRC27',isActive=true);
  insert pro;


  // set up pricebook and Verify that the results are as expected.
  Pricebook2 pb2 = new Pricebook2(Name='NONDIE');
  insert pb2; 
PriceBook2 pb2Standard = [select Id from Pricebook2 where IsStandard=true];


  // set up pricebookentry and Verify that the results are as expected.


  PricebookEntry pbe = new PricebookEntry(unitprice=1,Product2Id=pro.Id,isActive=true,Pricebook2Id=pb2Standard.Id,UseStandardPrice = false
);
   insert pbe;


 // set up opportunitylineitem and Verify that the results are as expected.

 OpportunityLineItem OPplineitem= new OpportunityLineItem (Quantity=2, OpportunityId=op.Id,UnitPrice=1,PriceBookEntryId=pbe.id );

  insert OPplineitem;

  test.stopTest();

  InvoiceController ic = new InvoiceController();

  apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().put('opId',op.id);

     }                        
  }
```

Any example plz.

Comment: Asking a question about code, but not posting any code, is not likely to get you any good answers. Post the code you have tried, and tell us what's wrong.

Comment: @Jeremy Nottingham:I have updated the code.

Answer (score 1):

Formula field will generate automatically.
You have to just give the dependent fields data for formula fields in test class & insert data.

if you have one formula field i.e salary__c which is having formula Basic__c + HRA__c then in test class you have to insert value for
Basic__c & HRA__c only & Salary__c will automatically calculated.

For if conditions suppose you are checking for
If(Salary__c>3000)
{
   your code
}
For above condition you have to give Basic & HRA value like 5000,2500 So that your condition will be satisfied and coverage will be increase.